# Issues with Jenkins Summary Display Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins to run some benchmarks and would like to use summary display plugin to publish performance numbers on the build page.

This is how I'm using the plugin in the job
[Plugin Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awK59.png)

Attached is the sample xml file (downloaded from plugin's website) . After the build is done the file is created at

```
%WORKSPACE%\BenchmarkRunnerSuite\logs\
```

[xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WxfS.png)

I'm archiving it and then providing the relative path. After the build is done I don't get any errors but also no output is shown on the result page.
[Result page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJDOs.png)

Can anyone help with properly setting up the Summary Display plugin. Also, it will be really helpful if anyone can share an XML template example for summary plugin.